# Geofire is archived, should I still use it?

Tags: firebase, geolocation, android-location, geofire

I recently noticed that Geofire has been archived on Github: https://github.com/googlearchive/geofire

Fortunately Geofire continues to work but I don't know for how long. Will depending on it harm my work in the future? Are there any other libraries like it?

Comment: If you're mostly in need of a way to store geographic points, Firestore does have a type for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint

Comment: Looking to store and display points @HondaGuy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There are three active Geofire projects:

- [geofire-js](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js) for JavaScript developers
- [geofire-java](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) for Android developers
- [geofire-objc](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) for iOS developers

There is also a [top-level Geofire project](https://github.com/googlearchive/geofire) that was meant to contain things that cross the languages. But it was never updated that top-level project after we created it, so we archived it about half a year ago. The Geofire libraries for the specific languages are still active though.